# Foreach Every Control on all forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, controls

I want to `manipulate` all `Controls` within my `form` using a `foreach loop`, I currently am using the following method:

```
 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
 {
                ComponentResourceManager resourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Main));
                resourceManager.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
  }
```

The problem with this `foreach`, is that Controls within `Containers` aren't included.

How Can I include all the `Controls` within the `Containers` too?

I would like to do this in 1 or maybe 2 `foreach` loops.

Comment: Are they not in the controls collection?

Comment: No all the Controls, that are not in a container and the containers itself will be included, but I want to select the Controls within the containers too.

Comment: Put the `ComponentResourceManager resourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Main));` out from loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Controls

Add the following class to your project:

```
public static class ControlExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetOffsprings(this Control @this)
    {
        foreach (Control child in @this.Controls)
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var offspring in GetOffsprings(child))
                yield return offspring;
        }
    }
}
```

It will return all sub controls of the caller:

```
var offsprings = this.GetOffsprings();
```

You can use it in the loop:

```
foreach (Control c in this.GetOffsprings())
{
    // Do action
}
```

### Menu items

Add the following class to your project:

```
public static class MenuStripExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> GetSubItems(this ToolStrip @this)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem child in @this.Items)
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var offspring in child.GetSubItems())
                yield return offspring;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> GetSubItems(this ToolStripItem @this)
    {
        if (!(@this is ToolStripDropDownItem))
            yield break;

        foreach (ToolStripItem child in ((ToolStripDropDownItem) @this).DropDownItems)
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach (var offspring in child.GetSubItems())
                yield return offspring;
        }
    }
}
```

It will return all sub menu items of the caller:

```
var allMenuItems = this.menuStrip1.GetSubItems()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, only one more little question, I also need to get the Menuitems from a Menustrip, How can I reach them and their sub menu items?

Answer (score 2):

Make it recursive:

```
private static void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager resourceManager,
                                   CultureInfo cultureInfo,
                                   Control container)
{
    foreach (var control in container.Controls)
    {
        resourceManager.ApplyResources(control, control.Name, cultureInfo);
        ApplyResources(resourceManager, cultureInfo, control);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var resourceManager = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Main));
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(lang);
ApplyResources(resourceManager, cultureInfo, this);
```